# Return results from data table in a sequence using linq

Tags: linq, datatable

I'm fetching rows from excel sheet in my application that holds attendance records from the bio metric machine. In order to get the best result i have to remove the redundant data. For that I have to manage check in and checkout timings at regular intervals. For instance, First check in time for entering, and then checkout time for lunch, then again check in for returning back, and last check out for going home. Meanwhile the rows in excel contains multiple check ins and check outs as the employee tends to do more that once for both.

I have managed to get records from excel and added to data table. Now for the sequence and sorting part I'm struggling to achieve my desired result. Below is my code.

```
  protected void btnSaveAttendance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile && Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) == ".xls")
            {
                using (var excel = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
                {
                    var tbl = new DataTable();
                    var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
                    var hasHeader = true;  // adjust accordingly
                                           // add DataColumns to DataTable
                    foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                        tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text
                            : String.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));

                    // add DataRows to DataTable
                    int startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
                    for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                    {
                        var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                        DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
                        foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                            row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
                    }

                    var distinctNames = (from row in tbl.AsEnumerable()
                                         select row.Field<string>("Employee Code")).Distinct();

                    DataRow[] dataRows = tbl.Select().OrderBy(u => u["Employee Code"]).ToArray();

                    var ss = dataRows.Where(p => p.Field<string>("Employee Code") == "55").ToArray();


                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
```

The result i'm getting is:

```
Employee Code   Employee Name      Date Time       In / Out
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 8:59    IN
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 8:59    IN
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 13:00   OUT
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 13:00   OUT
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 13:48   IN
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 13:49   IN
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 18:08   OUT
```

And I want to have first In and then out and then in and then out. This would iterate four times to generate the result.

Expected result is:

```
Employee Code   Employee Name       Date Time      In / Out
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 8:59    IN
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 13:00   OUT
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 13:48   IN
 55                   Alex         12/27/2018 18:08   OUT
```

Comment: You need to update database table restructured Parent & its child for attendence checkin / checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do **groupby** in the result like below

```
ss=ss.GroupBy(x=>x.DateTime).ToArray();
```

Build a logic, if your result have 2 successive In/Out as a sample like below.
Here **In** I considered as field name

```
var tt;
for(int i=0;i<ss.Count();i++)
{
if(ss[i].In=="In" && (tt!=null || tt.LastOrDefault().In!="In"))
tt=ss[i];
else if(ss[i].In=="Out" && (tt!=null || tt.LastOrDefault().In!="Out"))
tt=ss[i];

}
```

Comment: group wouldn't do it. For a reason if employee checks in twice with a difference of one minute, then this would not work.

Comment: Without out punch, is there any possibility in your functionality to check-in 2 times?

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned in my question, the employee tend to check in twice just in case if first time the record was not entered.

Comment: well i have already built up the logic now. I wanted to achieve this through linq, but perhaps it is not doable at the moment. The logic is quite similar to what you have posted. Thanks for the help :)